# What will happen to my existing iOS apps using Parse PushService once the parse server shuts down?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have two iOS apps using the Parse SDK to register for Push Notifications using the PushService.  Some portion of my user base will not update their apps immediately.  How will those apps behave once the parse API server shuts down after January 2017?

As I see it there are two parts to this question:
What response should I expect to receive when invoking APIs on https://api.parse.com after the service shuts down?  Should I expect a 404 error, complete silence, or something else?

The second portion of the question pertains to what to expect from the Parse iOS SDK when receiving the response from the first portion of the question.  My existing apps are invoking the saveInBackground method on the PFObject subclassed as PFInstallation objects in order to synchronize my Push Notification settings with Parse.  As I understand it, this portion of the SDK spawns a background thread that makes HTTP calls on api.parse.com.  How does this SDK code handle the HTTP response (or lack of response) from the first question?

Comment: I think that when parse.com will not be available anymore also the PushService will be unavailable because when you send a push via parse.com it first goes to parse.com server and from there to APNS so because the API will not be available nothing will happened.

Comment: @RanHassid, thanks for your comment.  So you suspect that without a server to respond, that the Parse SDK for iOS will do nothing?  Do you have any evidence, or documentation for this?

Comment: You don't need an evidence you just need to understand the flow.  In order to support push notification you need to add your certificate inside the parse.com dashboard without adding it the push will not work that's mean that the server send communicate with APNS also I never heard about communication between client to APNS directly .. There is always server involved in the middle and in your case it's the parse server .

Comment: @RanHassid You are correct, the mobile client is not communicating directly with APNS.  I agree, that once the Parse server shuts down, there will be nothing on the server side to initiate push notifications, so the mobile clients will not get any push notifications.  That wasn't what I was asking about.  My question concerned the behavior of the mobile client during its initial registration with Parse.  A Parse SDK method is invoked by our app on launch, which sends the app token to the Parse server.  I want to know what this SDK call will do once the server goes dark.  Thanks for commenting!

Comment: He will get timeout. so in your block you will get error that the request timed out